# How to find out if a Object is a integer or is a string or is a boolean?

Tags: java

I have an object and I want to detect what type is, so I can call

```
if (obj isa Integer)
  put(key,integerval);  
if (obj isa String)
    put(key,stringval);  
if (obj isa Boolean)
    put(key,booleanval);
```

Comment: There's not much point doing this. Even if you unbox the values before inserting them in your dictionary, they will be boxed again automatically.

Comment: I am running a query with the contentvalues, and was dealing with columns as string, so I get  ERROR/ContentValues(104): Cannot parse Integer value for true at key should_sync

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're pretty close, actually!

```
if (obj instanceof Integer)
    put(key,integerval);  
if (obj instanceof String)
    put(key,stringval);  
if (obj instanceof Boolean)
    put(key,booleanval);
```

From the [JLS 15.20.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.20.2):

> *RelationalExpression* `instanceof` *ReferenceType*
>
> At run time, the result of the `instanceof` operator is `true` if the value of the *RelationalExpression* is not `null` and the reference could be cast (§15.16) to the *ReferenceType* without raising a `ClassCastException`. Otherwise the result is `false`.

Looking at your usage pattern, though, it looks like you may have bigger issues than this.

Comment: What issues, I don't understand.

Comment: Well, as Mark Byers alluded to in his comment, this snippet just looks plain weird. It's hard to evaluate without looking at the whole context, but as far as your original question goes, `instanceof` is what you want. I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Beware: This only works if the Object is a String or an Integer before it is copied to an Object.  IE:
    
    `Obj num = "1";`
    `boolean isnum = num instanceof Integer;`
    `return isnum;`

would return false.

Comment: This is an old question, but I am having this issue right now, and as far as I know instanceof is a code smell. I know there exists the visitor pattern, but I am not sure if it really a great solution here, because you cannot add a visit method to Integer and String. So I was wondering, is this considered a good solution, or is there a way to avoid instanceof?